# Rolling Increase based on Category in R

Tags: r, calculation

I have this data frame with 3 columns and I need a 4th column which makes the increase of the value for each Fund for each date, in this case it is only possible for 2022-01-02 values.

```
Date <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-02","2022-01-02")
Fund <-c("A","B","C","C","A","B")
Values <- c(10,10,10,13,17,15)
```

For example this would be one result

| Date | Fund | Value | Increase % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 17 | 70% |

Answer (score 1):

An approach is to take the `diff` after grouping by 'Fund' and divide by the `first` value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Fund) %>% 
   mutate(Prop = 100 * c(0, diff(Values)/first(Values))) %>%
   ungroup
```

---

Or could be divide by the `lag` of 'Values'

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Fund) %>%
   mutate(Prop = 100 * c(0, diff(Values))/lag(Values)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, first solution work properly but Im afraid the second one does not, I'll really appreciate if you can correct it because in fact, I need to calculate not just one column but 5 with diferrent lags, daily, weekly, monthly, etc

Comment: @MatiasOchoa first solution was based on the percent increase from the first element of 'Values', where as the second one is based on the increment from previous value (assuming there are more than 2 elements per Fund)

Comment: The reason I provided two solutions is because your example data had only 2 rows per Fund and thus it was not clear whether the increment is calculated based on the first element or the previous adjacent element.  The second part of your comment is not provided in your original question `I need a 4th column which makes the increase of the..` i.e. 5 different lags is out of scope within the framework of this question.  You may post as a new questioin.